# Replacing 700x32c with 700x35c - does it matter?

Tags: tire

I need to replace the front tyre and tube on my Ridgeback Motion commuter bike.
I accidently asked my helpful shopper to get me 700x35c when what I'm replacing is 700x32c.

Does it matter? Will this new tube and tire fit? Will it affect performance in any meaningful way? I don't really understand tires sizing so not sure how much difference there is between 32 and 35 - is this the width? The width of which bit?

Comment: It will barely make a difference. Wide tires offer slightly more comfort/suspension (assuming you adjust the pressure low enough). Unless you were at the very limit of your rims or frame/brake clearance the tire should also just fit fine. The stated width is the approximate width of the tire when mounted. Actual width can vary slightly depending on your rims and manufacturing tolerances.

Comment: In itself, the difference between the two tire widths doesn't really make a difference. However, what does make a difference is if the wider tire requires a lower pressure. Tire pressure has a significant impact on rolling resistance, and if you are riding on good roads, the higher the pressure, the less resistance. On the other hand, if you are riding bad paths, lower tire pressure gives less resistance. It really depends on your application and on whether the optimum pressure is within the supported pressure range of the tire.